# Java - Validate XML against schema file approaches

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation

I am looking for a JAVA API which is capable of validating XML against Schema and document all the validation errors.
I have found some snippet of code for this but looking for a concrete solution.

Please share your thoughts.

Regards
Jai

Answer (score 0):

A concrete solution is to use the Java API for XML Processing (JAXP):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/validating.html